# How to enable Windows diagnostic / descriptive / detailed startup mode that shows what it's doing?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting, diagnostic

During the boot process, Windows normally displays that monolithic "Logging on.." screen.  There's a way to switch it to show what's going on behind the scenes, (e.g., connecting to network, running this program, arbitrary delay, etc.).  How do I enable this mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is called enabling verbose status messages. You can use the methods mentioned in the following links to turn it on.

http://www.techyard.net/how-to-verbose-startup-for-xp/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376

A word of caution - the MS link only mentions XP Pro, not Home, so I don't know if any of the methods referred to would work with XP Home. Also, it will affect shutdown, login and logoff too.

From the first link :

> To enable verbose status message in
>   Windows, just follow the few simple
>   steps below.
>
> 1. Go to Start > Run, type regedit and click OK.
> 2. Navigate to
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\
>   CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>
> 3. Right click at an empty area on the right pane, select New > DWORD Value
>      and type VerboseStatus.
> 4. Now double click on the new verbosestatus key that you just
>      created and enter the value data as 1.
> 5. Again, right click at an empty area on the right pane, select NEW > DWORD
>      Value and type DisableStatusMessages.
>      By default, the value data should be
> 6. Leave it as it is.

Comment: Aha, "verbose".  That's what I was looking for.  Could you quote the entire answer from the 1st link into your post?

Comment: That's a little lengthy, so I've just posted the first of the three methods, minus the graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I can't attest to Windows XP (sorry I don't have a machine to try it on) but in 7,

Run -> msconfig -> Boot and check the box "Boot Log"

Hope that helps!