# Show progress details when "Restarting..."/"Updating".. on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, windows-8.1, reboot

I've seen a tweaked version of windows 8.1 that claims it will show the user exactly what Windows is doing when it's restarting or booting or any other annoying undetermined progress.

Those undetermined processes sometimes halts for a long time (sometimes I give up and make an hard reset - a thing I wish I could avoid by really knowing if the process is stuck or just taking too long).

Comment: There is a registry key which can give detailed status messages during while starting, shutting down, and logging on/off. It has been around since Windows 2000, and it's supported in Windows 8.x too. Start `regedit`, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, create a new DWORD value called `VerboseStatus` and make sure it's set to `1`. Log off to apply the changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display additional boot and shutdown information on the Windows 7 welcome screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/426029/), [How to enable Windows diagnostic / descriptive / detailed startup mode that shows what it's doing?](http://superuser.com/questions/53382/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@and31415 gave me exactly what I've wanted in his comment (thanks!):

Start -> Run -> regedit.

Navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

create a new `DWORD` value called `VerboseStatus` and make sure it's set to `1`.

Log off to apply the changes.