# How to see what's going on during Windows shutdown/logging off process?

Tags: windows, shutdown, msconfig

Windows 7 **msconfig** lets users select the options **No GUI boot** and **OS boot information** to have a list of drivers being loaded during boot. Is it possible to have similar detailed messages during shutting down/restarting/logging off? Here's the screen I want disable or give me more details:

[image: Shutting down Windows 7]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you try to explain what you want, preferably with an example?

Comment: @LPChip I think what he wants is to replicate the *No GUI Boot* feature for shutdown, ie. *No GUI Shut down*...

Comment: Yes, I want to do what what @shub said.

Comment: I want to know what step of the shutdown process is making it slower.

Comment: I think you're looking for this then: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows. It tells you exactly what is happening during boot up/shut down, without removing GUI, it says things instead of 'shutting down...'

Comment: @shub I've rewritten my question and posted the steps in your link as an answer. Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display additional boot and shutdown information on the Windows 7 welcome screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/426029/), [How to enable Windows diagnostic / descriptive / detailed startup mode that shows what it's doing?](http://superuser.com/questions/53382/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From user **@shub** [helpful link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows):

1. Run **gpedit.msc** from the Start menu search
2. Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System
3. In the right pane, double-click on **Verbose vs normal status messages**

Once enabled, this setting makes the system display detailed status messages that show each step in the process of starting, shutting down, logging on, or logging off the system.

However, if the “Remove Boot / Shutdown / Logon / Logoff status messages” setting is enabled, this setting will be ignored.

--

Update: I've ended using [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/347191/33758) and found out that Comodo Firewall was the problematic program. After reinstalling it, Windows now shutdowns normally.

Comment: For those looking for this setting, it has seemingly been renamed in Windows 10 as "Display highly detailed status messages", but it's still in the same location.

Answer (score 12):

There can be many reasons Windows takes a long time to shutdown. Here are some ways to find out why and to speed it up:

Why:

1. [Enable Verbose Mode](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows). This tells you what is happening during shut down, like 'Stopping Services':

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type `regedit`
   - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
   - Right click on the right pane, New > DWORD Value. Name it `verbosestatus`. Double click it, make the value `1`.
2. Check the Event Log:

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type `eventvwr.msc`
   - Go to Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Diagnostics / Performance > Operational.
   - Sort the 'Task Category' column alphabetically.
   - Look at all items under the category 'Shutdown Performance Monitoring'
   - Try to spot anything odd.

What to do:

3. Change the delay before programs are force closed:

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type `regedit`
   - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control`
   - Double click the `WaitToKillServiceTimeout`
   - Set the value to something smaller (milliseconds - 1000 = 1 seconds)
4. [Use Windows Performance Toolkit (this is a link to another SuperUser answer)](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown/347191#347191)
5. [Perform a clean-boot](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-is-very-slow-to-shutdown/fb35a679-c9b8-4a97-95c4-39c60e218130):

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Type `msconfig`
   - Click General tab > Selective Startup
   - Uncheck Load Startup items
   - Click the Services tab, check the Hide all Microsoft Services box, and then click Disable All
   - Click OK, and when you are prompted, click Restart.

Now, this should speed it up a lot. From the previous steps, if you are suspicious about any programs, then un-check them first. Then start enabling one-by-one and see which one is causing the problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: I ended up using [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://superuser.com/a/347191/33758) and found out that Comodo Firewall was the problematic program.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the eventlog? It will log all problems during startup/shutdown.

You are likekly to find the problem in the system log, but if an application were to hang, it would be in the application log instead.