# It takes nearly 10 minutes for my Windows 11 (Home Edition) to shut down

Tags: windows-11

Similarly as a few people before me, I have a problem to shut down my computer. I am running a Windows 11 (Home) - it takes less than a minute to boot up, but it takes over 7 minutes to shut down. My computer is about 1 month old, brand new gaming computer with SSD as a primary disk.

When I boot up the computer and try to shut it down straight away, it shuts in less than 30 seconds. However, when I use it (e.g. browsing the internet, or using MS Word, Blender, etc.) and then I try to shut it down, then it will take close to 10 minutes to shut down, and YES, I always close all applications before I try to shut it down. It would shut down when I hold the ON button, but I don't think that is 'safe' solution.

I don't think there is any hardware issue as it is brand new desktop computer. It might be a driver issue, similar like someone reported before, but how will I find out? I don't really want to reinstall everything. Any other suggestion? Is there any quick solution to this? It seems this is not uncommon problem with Windows. Thank you in advance for any suggestion, much appreciated!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd start with this

Comment: And make sure you let it install any and all pending updates.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/N0ZICHG.jpeg

Comment: Try enabling Verbose Mode and checking the event log.  See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/758657/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-windows-shutdown-logging-off-process).  Then [edit] your question, tell us what you did, and tell us what happened.

Comment: Thank you for the links, Gantendo; will try and will let you know if the problem remains or not. I have also notice that ejecting USB stick takes very long time (nearly a minute), even though the stick is not used by any application.

Comment: My installation is up-to-date and I do not have any pending update, ChanganAuto

Comment: Check your disk : run `chkdsk` and check the SMART attributes of the disk. You may add the attributes into your post for us, if you like. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Just curious, for your SSD what speeds are you getting during r/w tests? You can run a test this Crystal Disk Mark: https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/

Comment: @Gantendo - I followed the instructions on the *.jpeg image and it seems the problem is resolved! My computer now shuts down within 20 sec. Thank you for your kind advice and sharing your expertise, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @harrymc - I've checked the disk, all good, thanks for your suggestion. The problem is now resolved thanks to Gantendo

Comment: You have only worked around the problem - which service it is that refuses to shutdown in reasonable time? If you don't know, you might find some information in the Event Viewer about the service being killed.